# subtracting values group wise on a tibble

Tags: r, dplyr, tibble

I have a simple tibble and want to calculate the absolute difference of values after grouping them:

```
tibb <- tibble(id = c("A", "B", "C","A", "B", "C"), value = c(5,4,3,7,8,9))

# A tibble: 6 x 2
  id    value
  <chr> <dbl>
1 A         5
2 B         4
3 C         3
4 A         7
5 B         8
6 C         9

tibb %>% group_by(id) %>% summarize(diff = function(x,y){abs(x-y)})
```

dplyr return an error stating diff is not supported.

The output should looks like this:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  id      sum
  <chr> <int>
1 A         2
2 B         4
3 C         6

Error in summarise_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Column `diff` is of unsupported type function
```

Is there any way to calculate this?

Comment: Is there always just two values per id group? If so you can `summarize(diff=abs(first(value)-last(value)))`

Comment: Even simpler than what @aichao suggests is the function `diff`, but as they point out, for that to work depends on whether this needs to scale beyond 2 values per ID

Comment: @camille: the reason not to use `diff` is because we are summarizing here and `diff` produces a vector. Of course, if the groups are always two values, this is not a problem, but the code should always be consistent to avoid errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there are 2 values in each group then try this:

```
tibb <- tibble(id = c("A", "B", "C","A", "B", "C"), value = c(5,4,3,7,8,9))
tibb

tibb %>% group_by(id) %>% summarize(diff = abs(diff(value)))
#or
tibb %>% group_by(id) %>% summarize(diff = abs(value[1] - value[2]))
```